# Why is this alias not working?

Tags: shell, alias

So I've setup this alias:

```
alias stat='myvar=3; myothervar=3; stat'
```

basically, when running stat, I also want to set two vars

and this works

```
echo $myvar

stat
<stat output shown>
echo $myvar
3
```

however, if i execute `stat` as follows, it no longer works:

```
myvar=0
echo $myvar
0
currentUser=$(stat -f %Su "/dev/console")
<stat output shown>
echo $myvar
0
```

Why wasn't `myvar` 3 in case i ran the command as part of a `$()` construct?

Comment: @muru Not _quite_ a dupe, but the subshell that the command substitution runs in is probably the culprit here as well (it does not inherit the aliases). Not answering as I never use aliases and don't know how they work (I tend to use shell functions instead).

Comment: @Kusalananda I'm reasonably sure the alias is run in the command substitution, but setting a variable in it has no effect in the parent shell

Comment: @muru You're absolutely correct. I forgot that the alias was setting variables' values. It does look like a dupe then.

Comment: @Kusalananda - would a function be an alternative in this situation?

Comment: @Adelin No. I misunderstood your use case in my first comment. You would have to  make sure that the assignments are _not_ run in a subshell, which means that you can't assign the output of `stat` to a variable in a command substitution _and_ set variables at the same time. If the alias (or function) did _all_ assignments (to `myvar`, `myothervar` and `currentUser`), then it would work as the assignments would not happen in a subshell.